# Use the name within an object to name a dataframe in a list

Tags: r

Difficult to explain but hope this code will help

```
df <- mtcars    
list_of_dataframes <- list(  "table_mtcars" = df )
```

If you run the two lines above it gets to the result I want, a list that contains the dataframe and the the dataframe named as "table_mtcars".
Is there a way to use a name in an object to get the same result. For example, this is the object

```
tablename <- "table_mtcars" # tablename contains the name of table that i want to use
```

Then I've tried these

```
list_of_datasets <- list( tablename  = df )
list_of_datasets <- list( eval(tablename ) = df )
list_of_datasets <- list( parse(tablename ) = df )
list_of_datasets <- list( eval(parse(text= tablename )) = df )
```

None of these work. Is there a way to do this? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `list_of_datasets  <- setNames(list(df), tablename)`? e.g. for multiples, `setNames(list(df, df), c(tablename, "other name"))`

Comment: Brilliant, that's excellent thanks. Probably one for new question, but is there a way to add a another e.g. setNames(list(df2), tablename2) to the existing list_of_datasets list?

Comment: perhaps `list_of_datasets <- c(list_of_datasets, setNames(list(df2), tablename2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you could use:

```
list_of_datasets  <- setNames(list(df), tablename)
```

to make a named list using the dataframe `df` with the name `tablename`.

As @r2evans noted, you could incrementally add additional element `df2` with name `tablename2` using:

```
list_of_datasets <- c(list_of_datasets, setNames(list(df2), tablename2))
```